# How to close input stream in c++?

Tags: c++

So what im trying to do is to allow user to input name, age, education.
If user ended adding data, by entering `'s'` the program moves to sorting.
If user didnt enter `'s'` the input loop continues, and user may add more people. 
So at line: `std::cin>>stop;`. I'm opening input stream to check if user entered `'s'`. If they didn't - this input should be closed, and then new input should start at line: `while(std::cin>>name>>age>>education)` - to add more people.

My question is how to close this `std::cin>>stop;` input? If it's not closed, the first character of name will be put into char stop, and name will be lacking the first character.

`std::cin.unget()` does the trick but its not exactly the purpose it should serve, because if the the type of stop is changed from char to std::string, the whole name will be put into stop variable.

```
int main()
{
    int age;
    std::string name, education;
    std::vector<Data> zbior;
    std::cout << "Enter: name, age, education: ex: Ala 20 primary" << std::endl;
    while(std::cin>>name>>age>>education)
    {
        zbior.push_back(Data(name, age, education));
        char stop;
        std::cout << "Type s to end input or continue adding data" << std::endl;
        std::cin>>stop;
        if(stop == 's') break;
        else  std::cin.unget();


    system("cls");
    sortManual();

    std::string sort;

    while (std::cin>>sort) {
        if(sort =="ar") { system("cls"); print_young_to_elder(zbior); std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;  sortManual();}
        if(sort =="am") { system("cls"); print_elder_to_younger(zbior); std::cout << "\n"; sortManual();}
        if(sort =="er") { system("cls"); print_Edu_rising(zbior); std::cout << "\n"; sortManual();}
        if(sort =="em") { system("cls"); print_Edu_descending(zbior); std::cout << "\n"; sortManual();}
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep on reading data, but a different data, you do not want to close the input stream. It can be very hard to open it again. Instead read `name` separately from the other inputs and exit the if `name` is `"s"`. If `name` is not `"s"`, read the rest of the inputs.an continue with the loop.

Comment: You may want to use a different variable name than `sort`.  `std::sort` is function in the `std` namespace, when you include the `algorithm` header.

Comment: I recommend to `transform` your input string to all lower case or all upper case before comparing.  The following are not equal: AR, ar, Ar, aR.

Answer (score 0):

Please use string not char to read one of the words (like name) and compare it to your "s" and if equal take approprioate action.

I would not reverse input streams or things like that in that simple program as it like adds a layer of complication when it is not needed..